# Nginx: use a directory as root /

Tags: nginx, directory, config, root

As the title tells I would like to use a directory as my root on my Nginx server.
I have a directory tree something like this:

```
/www
folder A
Folder B
Folder C
```

And I would like to configure Nginx so that the root / should be i folder A (example.com/ would be in the folder A). But if a user types example.com/FolderB/ that user should jump up one directory and get to the folder B. And the same for folder C.

I've tried to use locations, alias and  root to change where the user is but I don't get it to work proper.

Answer (score 0):

Set the root of the site to /www.
Then add a try_files to the root location:

```
root /www;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /A/$uri /A/$uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: Didn't get that to work. It gives me a 403. It tries to open index.php in /www folder

Comment: Maybe you didn't add an `index index.html index.php;`? Or the permissions on the folders are not right?

Comment: Ye, that was my first thought. But i will post my config here:        
server{
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
root /www;
index index.html index.php;
client_max_body_size 10m;

# remove .php from url
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php; }

# folderA as root
try_files $uri $uri/ /folderA/$uri /folderA/$uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}



}